# Wanted add boarder color to column

Tags: javascript

```js
var boarder_color=function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++ ){
    temp.push({
        title:"Compared",
        borderColor : boarder_color, // I want to add boarder color to this column
        columns:[
            {title:"val", field:"setting", width:"95", sortable:true, headerFilter:"input"},
            {title:"feild", field:"val", formatter:"textarea", headerFilter:"input", width:"150"},
        ],
    })
}

var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    resizableRows:true,
    fitColumns:true,
    height: (window.innerHeight > 130 ? window.innerHeight - 130 : 1),
    index:"serial",
    columns: temp,
});
```

I'm very new to javascript seems my question may not contain the required information. Any help will be highly appreciated

I referred the following link : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_border

Comment: What are you doing with this temp array? Whats your actual requirement?

Comment: Now I think it has required information

Answer (score 1):

You could use css classes, so for example:

```
.redBorder{
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Then use the cssClass property on the column definition to add this class to the cell

```
//column definition
{title:"val", field:"setting", cssClass:"redBorder"},
```

Though it is worth noting that you can only apply borders to actual columns not column groups.

Or if you need to do it on a cell by cell basis you can use a custom formatter:

```
//column definition
{title:"val", field:"setting", formatter:function(cell){
        cell.getElement().style.border= "1px solid #ff0000";
        return cell.getValue();
    }
},
```